# How do I change my code to correct the error?

Tags: python

My code shows these two errors, when the code running at drawing pictures. And I don't know how to correct it

```
t, x, fig2a = q2.brusselator_plot(t0, t_max, a, b1, N)
```

Error Raised:

> Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '0.5'

```
t, x, fig2b = q2.brusselator_plot(t0, t_max, a, b2, N)
```

Error Raised:

> Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '2.0'

Comment: Please review how to create a [Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We have no way of reproducing your error, which means we can only guess at what causes the error.

Comment: Could you at least provide code for the `q2.brusselator_plot` or any info about this